# Toilet pipeline 2 holes spraying Temporary fix please Main shut off for 2 days

Tags: repair, toilet, pipe, leaking, temporary

I found 2 holes that were spraying water in my toilet pipeline and am needing a temporary fix. I have been without water for 2 days and can not get anyone here for a week Is this easy to replace. I have no experience [image]

Comment: please point where is it leaking

Comment: If (seems unlikely with a hack job like that) there's a valve for this line at the supply side, turn it off, and fill the toilet tank with a bucket until you can get it fixed.

Comment: Second the request for an indication of exactly where it is leaking from. Given what you're starting with,  if the problem is pinholes in the tubing I wouldn't be opposed to a hideous epoxy-putty lump wrapped around the tube as a very temporary stopgap. If it's at the connector (disconnected in the photo), it might just not have been tightened down properly.

Comment: Quick question: Do you own this building, or rent? If you're renting, the landlord is supposed to be responsible for fixing this sort of thing unless they delegate it to you and ask you to send them the bill. (At least that's true everyplace I've lived.)

Comment: And, as long as this is being repaired, you might have a shutoff valve installed. As mentioned, in many locales this would not meed code.

Comment: Is that carpet? :-o

Comment: @Ruskes There are four score lines The two pinholes are  in the middle of them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal. There is no shut off valve

Comment: @keshlam Yes they are pinholes and I will definitely try hideous epoxy-putty lumps I do own my home.  I disconnected the line from toilet to try silicone tape and of course that didn’t help Thank you for a very temporary solution

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I just called plumbers again and since this is an ‘89 mobile home two of the four will not work on it and still can not come for a week. I will definitely have a shut off valve installed.  There are no others in the whole home

Comment: @Huesmann. Yes the whole house is carpet  Not my idea

Comment: This could be a DIY job. Where does the pipe comes from, can you access that

Comment: @Ruskes I purchased some epoxy putty and it is holding for now.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should immediately go to the shut-off valve that serves the branch to the toilet, and close that valve. That should stop the leaking.  If there is no such valve, or it leaks, then put out an emergency call to a plumber and have them add it.  No one is going to wait you make a week for an emergency.  If it's a rental situation and the landlord is balking, check your state laws for whether you have a right to get a plumber out and withhold the bill from the next rent.

By itself, a successfully shut-off water line to a toilet is not an emergency. You can refill the top tank manually using buckets from the tub, and the toilet will work normally in all respects.  (Except for giving you a chore).

Comment: Thank you very much. There is no shut off valve. I have to keep the main turned off and all 4 plumbers have said a week or more.  I appreciate your help very much